# Why my Java servlet auto login code works for Firefox but not IE?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, servlets, autologin

I took over a Sring MVC project and need to change its behavior, so in my servlet I send a get request to automatically login, my servlet code looks like this :

```
...
  public class ServletFilter implements Filter
  {
    int Count=0;
    ...

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,ServletResponse servletResponse,FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,ServletException
    {

      if (Count==0)
      {
        String Login_URI="http://Example.com/SupportCenter/login.html?userName="+userName+"&password="+password;
        Count++;
        String result=sendGetRequest(Login_URI);
      }
    ...

      private String sendGetRequest(String url)
      { 
        StringBuffer response=new StringBuffer();
        String USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";
        // String USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";

        try
        {
          URL obj=new URL(url);
          HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)obj.openConnection();
          con.setRequestMethod("GET");
          con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

          int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
          System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : "+url);
    //    System.out.println("Response Code : "+responseCode);

          BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
          String inputLine;

          while ((inputLine=in.readLine()) != null) { response.append(inputLine); }
          in.close();
    //    System.out.println(response.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return response.toString();
      }
    ...
    }
```

When I ran it with Firefox, it logged me in, but didn't work in IE.

I also manually pasted the URL :

http://Example.com/SupportCenter/login.html?userName=UID&password=PSW

into both broswers, and they both logged me in.
So why when my servlet run in IE, it couldn't log me in ? And how can I see the interactions behind the scenes between the browsers and the servlet, so I simulate that ?

Comment: Do you mean when your servlet sends the IE user-agent through the `URL` object versus sending a Firefox user-agent?  Or do you mean when you go to the servlet with one browser versus the other? Also, what's the purpose of sending the hardcoded user-agent in the servlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why, just turn on cookies solved the problem.